# ocultar e mostrar div de cada coluna

Tags: php, javascript, html, banco-de-dados

**Olá, estou fazendo uma pagina de exibição de clientes cadastrados no banco de dados, fiz uma pagina aonde exibe toda a informação cadastrada no banco de dados, mais gostaria de ocultar todo conteúdo por padrão e só mostrar quando for clicado no nome do usuário cadastrado no banco de dados, mais o problema que eu estou tendo é que quando existe mais de 1 usuário cadastrado no banco de dados, exibe o nome dos 2 usuários corretamente, mais quando eu clico pra exibir os dados do segundo usuário, mostra apenas o primeiro que foi cadastrado, independente se eu clicar no 2° ou 3° usuário, exibe apenas os dados do primeiro da lista, já tentei separar mais não estou conseguindo!**

De uma olhada no meu exibir.php

```
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = "localhost";
$db   = "banco";
$user = "root";
$pass = "adm2020";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, nome, fone, login, senha, data, endereco, cpf FROM clientes");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>
<script>
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none")
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}</script>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
        <center><p>Cliente: <button onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')"><?=$linha['nome']?></button>
        <div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none"> <BR>ID: <?=$linha['id']?><br>Login: <?=$linha['login']?><br>Senha: <?=$linha['senha']?><br>Endereço: <?=$linha['endereco']?><br>Data: <?=$linha['data']?><br>Fone: <?=$linha['fone']?></p></div></center>
        
<?php

        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

O JavaScript e outras bibliotecas são otimizadas para trabalhar no pressuposto de que os IDs são únicos. Qualquer trabalho que o javascript tiver que realizar vai ser feito no primeiro `id` que encontrar, independentemente de quantos elementos tenham na página com o id igual.

Veja o exemplo a seguir

```js
function mostrarTexto(el) {
     var texto = document.getElementById(el).innerText;
     console.log(texto);
}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv" onclick="mostrarTexto('minhaDiv')">Clique-me, sou a primeira div</div>
<div id="minhaDiv" onclick="mostrarTexto('minhaDiv')">Clique-me, sou a segunda div</div>
<div id="minhaDiv" onclick="mostrarTexto('minhaDiv')">Clique-me, sou a terceira div</div>
```

> Portanto, na sua aplicação, acontece a mesma coisa, apenas os dados do primeiro usuário serão mostrados já que todas as `divs` estão sendo criadas com mesmo `id`, `<div id="minhaDiv"`.

**A solução** passa por introduzir uma variável que a cada iteração do loop `do while` seja incrementada e concatenada tanto ao id das divs `<div id="minhaDiv<?=$i?>` quanto ao parâmetro da função do botão `Mudarestado('minhaDiv<?=$i?>')`.

**Parte do exibir.php que foram feitas as modificações**

```
<?php
    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        $i=1; //INICIA CONTADOR
        do {
?>
        <center><p>Cliente: <button onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv<?=$i?>')"><?=$linha['nome']?></button>
        <div id="minhaDiv<?=$i?>" style="display:none"> <BR>ID: <?=$linha['id']?><br>Nome: <?=$linha['nome']?><br>Sobrenome: <?=$linha['sobrenome']?><br>Email: <?=$linha['email']?><br>Senha: <?=$linha['senha']?><br>Nivel Acesso: <?=$linha['nivelacesso']?></p></div></center>
        
<?php
         $i++;//INCREMENTA CONTADOR
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if
    }
?>
```

---

**Exemplo de resultado esperado**

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none")
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<p>Cliente: <button onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv1')">Jagunço</button>
        <div id="minhaDiv1" style="display:none"> <BR>ID: 53<br>Nome: Jagunço<br>Sobrenome: prado<br>Email: jagunco@mial.com<br>Senha: 11qqaazz<br>Nivel Acesso: basico</p></div>
        
<p>Cliente: <button onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv2')">Aparecida</button>
        <div id="minhaDiv2" style="display:none"> <BR>ID: 52<br>Nome: Aparecida<br>Sobrenome: Silva<br>Email: aparecida@mial.com<br>Senha: 11qqaazz<br>Nivel Acesso: basico</p></div>
        
<p>Cliente: <button onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv3')">Emme</button>
        <div id="minhaDiv3" style="display:none"> <BR>ID: 51<br>Nome: Emme<br>Sobrenome: Flaming<br>Email: emme@mail.com<br>Senha: zxcvbnmnb<br>Nivel Acesso: admin</p></div>
```

Comment: De uma olhada como ficou, acho que tem alguma coisa errada, na linha 49

Comment: editei a resposta de modo a não haver duvidas quanto a colocação da variável $i

Answer (score -1):

Veja como ficou

````
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = "localhost";
$db   = "banco";
$user = "root";
$pass = "adm2020";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, nome, fone, login, senha, data, endereco, cpf FROM clientes");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>
<script>

function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none")
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}
   $i=1; //INICIA CONTADOR
    do {}

</script>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        $i=1; //INICIA CONTADOR
        do {
?>
        <center><p>Cliente: <button onClick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv<?=$i?>')"><?=$linha['nome']?></button><br>
        <div id="minhaDiv<?=$i?>" style="display:none"> <BR>ID: <?=$linha['id']?><br>Login: <?=$linha['login']?><br>Senha: <?=$linha['senha']?><br>Endereço: <?=$linha['endereco']?><br>Data: <?=$linha['data']?><br>Fone: <?=$linha['fone']?></p></div></center>
        
<?php

     $i++;//INCREMENTA CONTADOR
    // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
    }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>```
````

Comment: Corrigi nesse código que vc postou, vc tinha colocado duas vezes $i++;//INCREMENTA CONTADOR e esqueceu de colocar $i=1; //INICIA CONTADOR no lugar onde mostrei na minha reposta

Comment: Esse $i=1; //INICIA CONTADOR, Fica dentro do script mudarestado? se possivel teria como mandar o código inteiro você mesmo?

Comment: Ah sim, agora consequi, nao tinha visto que tinha colocado duas vezes o incrementa contador! Agradeço pela ajuda, Salvou meu dia :)

Comment: Otimo, eu editei minha resposta, ficou mais claro, pode retirar essa sua resposta aqui e marcar a minha como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgbXR.png